# How do I save System.Drawing.Color value in an array? Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'system drawing color'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having errors `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Drawing.Color'`.

My code is as follows:

```
   ArrayList columnSelection = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList colourSelection = new ArrayList();
```

-

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            colourSelection[i] = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
```

-

```
String selection = ddlSelectColumn.SelectedValue;
String colour = ddlSelectColour.SelectedValue;

String colour1 = "System.Drawing.Color.";
colour = colour1 + colour;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  if (ddlSelectColumn.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals(i.ToString()))
  {
    colourSelection[i] = colour;
  }
}

for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
{
  Chart3.Series[a].Color = colourSelection[a]; <---- Error message here
}
```

This is my whole code, please let me know how can I solve this error.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of colourSelection[] ?

Comment: Please provide enough information. So you can get appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `colourSelection` is actually a `string[]` or an `objct[]` which contains the names,  you can use [`Color.FromName("Red");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the `Color`-instance:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
{
  Chart3.Series[a].Color = Color.FromName(colourSelection[a].ToString()); 
}
```

But then you don't need to prefix it with `System.Drawing.Color`, so replace this:

```
String colour1 = "System.Drawing.Color."; colour = colour1 + colour;
```

with

```
String colour1 = colour;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `colourSelection` is an array of objects. You can't assign an `object` to a `Color`, you need to cast it:

```
Chart3.Series[a].Color = (Color)colourSelection[a];
```

You can also use `as operator` for a safer cast, if you are not sure the underlying type of your object.

Comment: You can have a +1 from me as we've got pretty much identical answers :)

Comment: I assume that it's a `string[]`

Comment: @TimSchmelter in that case error message would be: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Color'`

Comment: @Selman22: you're right, i guessed that because of `String colour1 = "System.Drawing.Color."; colour = colour1 + colour;`. So it seems to be  an `object[]` which stores strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your `colourSelection[]` is an array of `object` instead of `System.Drawing.Color`. Either change it to be of the correct type (this is the preferred option as it provides type checking) or cast to `Color`:

```
Chart3.Series[a].Color = (System.Drawing.Color)colourSelection[a];
```